# Evaluating "null == <int>"

Tags: c#

This statement seems to work, but I'm not sure exactly how

```
int id = 0; // non-nullable ("primative"/value-type/struct)

_list?.Find(t => { return t?.Id == id; })?.DeptId ?? 0;
```

If `t` is *`null`*, then `t?.Id` is *`null`*, correct?

Then how is this legal:

```
null == id
```

---

**Update (5/8/18)**

The statement in visual studio

```
if (null == 0) {}
```

Gets highlighted green and upon inspection with a mouse over states

> "The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'

---

**Update (5/24/18)**

> ### **Nullable`<T>` Struct**
>
> **Fundamental Properties**
>
> The two fundamental members of the Nullable structure are the
>   HasValue and Value properties. If the HasValue property for a
>   Nullable object is true, the value of the object can be accessed
>   with the Value property. If the HasValue property is false, the value
>   of the object is undefined and an attempt to access the Value property
>   throws an InvalidOperationException.
>
> **Boxing and Unboxing**
>
> When a nullable type is boxed, the common language runtime
>   automatically boxes the underlying value of the Nullable object,
>   not the Nullable object itself. That is, if the HasValue property
>   is true, the contents of the Value property is boxed. When the
>   underlying value of a nullable type is unboxed, the common language
>   runtime creates a new Nullable structure initialized to the
>   underlying value.
>
> If the HasValue property of a nullable type is false, the result of a
>   boxing operation is null. Consequently, if a boxed nullable type is
>   passed to a method that expects an object argument, that method must
>   be prepared to handle the case where the argument is null. When null
>   is unboxed into a nullable type, the common language runtime creates a
>   new Nullable structure and initializes its HasValue property to
>   false.
>
> ref:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: It won't even do `t.id==Id` if t is null. It will simply return false. And BTW t.id will not be null ever as it is int not `int?`

Comment: `t?.Id` is of type `int?` (i.e. `Nullable<int>`), to which you *can* compare an `int`.

Comment: I guess because `null` on an integer evaluates to it's default value, as per any struct, in this case `0`.

Comment: @MongZhu `List<T>` where `Id` is a property of `T` (`public int Id {get;set;}`), so is nullable.

Comment: @samusarin sorry for that stupid question. My attention span has become too short for SO XD I guess I need to call it a day ;)

Comment: @MongZhu Heh, no worries I barely have capacity for even videogames after work these days. I knew what ya meant though... I am actually wrong, the `Id` property still returns a "primitive" (value-type) `int`, so it is not  nullable (I conflated things). However, the overloaded/lifted `==` operator still takes care of  casting/wrapping/boxing it into one.

Comment: @IanH. No, that's not true at all.  `null == 0` is false.  `null` is it's own value, equal to `null` and not equal to any other value.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm sorry I don't follow you?

Comment: `t?.Id == id` says that compare `t.Id` and `id` only if `t ` is not null and return true or false based on the comparison result. If `t` is null it will not do any comparison and simply return false.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/v9k5kh

Answer (score 3):

From the [C# 5.0 spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) (Section 7.3.7 **Lifted operators**):

> For the equality operators
>
> ```
> ==  !=
> ```
>
> a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and a null value unequal to any non-null value. If both operands are non-null, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.

Thus, the lifted operator `int? == int?` is used. Since the left-hand side is `null` and the right-hand side isn't, the operator returns `false`.

Comment: A college told me he suspected a "lifted operator", but I've never heard of such a thing so wanted to be sure. Thanks!.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11854/C-Nullable-Types

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/06/27/what-exactly-does-lifted-mean/

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/27/nullable-micro-optimization-part-two/